# boost::async_receive_from в методе класса

Tags: c++, сокет, сеть, boost

Класс должен открывать несклько сокетов, асинхронно их слушать и писать в буффер, выделенный класом.

В секции `private:` объявления:

```
std::vector<SHP_Socket> vecSock;
std::vector<udp::endpoint> vecEndpoint;
std::vector<uint8_t[8000]> vecData;
std::vector<uint8_t[8000]> vecData2;
```

, где `SHP_Socket` это: `typedef std::shared_ptr<udp::socket> SHP_Socket;`.

Инициализирую сокеты следующим образом:

```
SHP_Socket a;
udp::endpoint sender_endpoint;
a.reset(new udp::socket(io_service_, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), my_ports[i])));
vecSock.push_back(a);
```

Предполагаемый метод класса, который будет в отдельном потоке слушать данный сокет:

```
void Class::receive(const boost::system::error_code &err, std::size_t bytes, int i)
{
    if (bytes > 12)
    {
        memcpy(vecData2[i], vecData[i], bytes);
    }
    vecSock[i]->async_receive_from(buffer(vecData[i]), vecEndpoint[i], /*[1]*/);
}
```

Хочется, чтобы параметром `async_receive_from` передавалась опять функция `Class::receive`. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если именно её - воспульзуйтесь `boost::bind`/`std::bind`, но я бы так сделал (или около того):

```
void Class::startRecv(int i)
{
  vecSock[i]->async_receive_from(buffer(vecData[i]), vecEndpoint[i], [this, i](const boost::system::error_code &ec, std::size_t bytes) {
  if (bytes > 12)
  {
    memcpy(vecData2[i], vecData[i], bytes);
    startRecv(i); // я не знаю по какому критерию передавать i собираетесь.
  }
});
}
```

Либо вариант без лямбды:

```
void Class::startRecv(int i)
{
  vecSock[i]->async_receive_from(buffer(vecData[i]),
                                 vecEndpoint[i],
                                 boost::bind(&Class::onRecv, this, _1, _2, i));
}

void Class::onRecv(const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t bytes, int i)
{
  if (bytes > 12) 
  {
    memcpy(vecData2[i], vecData[i], bytes);
    startRecv(i); // я не знаю по какому критерию передавать i собираетесь.        
  }
}
```

Comment: переменная i (обозначает индекс сокета\клиента)пришла извне, при первом вызове receive. C лямбда мне нравится способ) И правильно ли я понимаю, что надо создать для каждого i надо запускать свою нить с io_service.run()? Предполагается, что данные пишутся в буффер, который использует родительская нить.

Comment: По хорошим практикам Asio я вам сильно не посоветую, но что бы распараллелить обслуживание да, `io_service.run()` нужно вызвать в каждом потоке.